# Combinatorial explanation for $2n$th moment of standard normal distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value, moments, combinatorics

The $2n^\text{th}$ moment of the standard normal distribution $X \sim \text{N}(0, 1)$ is given by:

$$\mathbb{E}(X^{2n}) = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!},$$

which is also the number of ways to divide $2n$ people into $n$ distinct pairs.  Is this just a coincidence, or is there some combinatorial explanation for this?

Comment: See Gian-Carlo Rota and Jianhong Shen, *On the Combinatorics of Cumulants.*  It's freely available online.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986015/standard-normal-moments-and-combinatorics/4188789

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a simple way to frame this in combinatorial terms, other than to observe the equivalency that you have already observed.  Nevertheless, a preliminary aspect of framing the result in combinatorial terms is to look at the moment generating function of the standard normal distribution.  The MGF and its [Maclaurin expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function) are given by:

$$m_Z(t) = \exp \Big( \frac{t^2}{2} \Big) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2\ell}}{2^\ell \ell!}.$$

To facilitate our analysis, let $\mathscr{C}(k)$ denote the class of sets of $2k$ people divided into $k$ distinct pairs, so we have:

$$|\mathscr{C}(k)| = \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}.$$

Differentiating the MGF $2n$ times gives:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^{2n} m_Z}{dt^{2n}}(t) 
&= \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \bigg( \frac{d}{dt} \bigg)^{2n} \frac{t^{2\ell}}{2^\ell \ell!} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^\ell \ell!} \bigg( \frac{d}{dt} \bigg)^{2n} t^{2\ell} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\ell=n}^\infty \frac{(2\ell)_{2n}}{2^\ell \ell!} \cdot t^{2\ell-2n} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{(2n+2\ell)!}{2^{n+\ell} (n+\ell)!} \cdot \frac{t^{\ell}}{(2 \ell)!} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty |\mathscr{C}(n+\ell)| \cdot \frac{t^{\ell}}{(2 \ell)!}, \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

and so the $2n$th raw moment is:

$$\mathbb{E}(Z^{2n}) = \frac{d^{2n} m_Z}{dt^{2n}}(0) = |\mathscr{C}(n)|.$$

As you can see, combinatorial terms similar to the one of interest to you occur when we differentiate the moment generating function.  This is a general result pertaining to that particular exponential function, so it is not something restricted to the normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben!!! I am fine with mathematical analogy but I was looking for the combinatorial explanation for this. I am going through Harvard's Stats110 course and encountered this: [link](https://youtu.be/tVDdx6xUOcs?t=1009). I couldn't find any simple logical explanation for their equivalence as mentioned by the prof, though. He skipped the part about the explanation!!!

Comment: It would be wonderful if you could ask your Professor for the reason and then post it as an answer --- it is not something I am particularly familiar with.

Comment: Actually I am going through online video lectures posted on YouTube. I will try to reach out to him and post the response if I found something!!!